# Slack's chat.scheduleMessage API keeps throwing Epoch time error

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to use chat.scheduleMessage from Slack API (https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage). However, I keep getting the error `time_too_far`.

Request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://slack.com/api/chat.scheduleMessage' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
--data-raw '{
    "channel":"#test_channel",
    "text":"Sample message",
    "post_at":"1596647160000"
}'
```

Response:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "time_too_far",
    "warning": "missing_charset",
    "response_metadata": {
        "warnings": [
            "missing_charset"
        ]
    }
}
```

As per the developer documentation, it says, `You will only be able to schedule a message up to 120 days into the future. If you specify a post_at timestamp beyond this limit, you’ll receive a time_too_far error response.`. However, in this case, I am just scheduling the message for tomorrow.

Not sure if I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp you're providing is a [JavaScript timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) (milliseconds since epoch), while Slack's [scheduled message API](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage) takes a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since epoch). Dividing by 1000 should fix the error.